# Use 32bit "Program Files" directory in msbuild

Tags: msbuild, x86, 64-bit, x86-64, program-files

In 64 bit versions of windows, 32 bit software is installed in "c:\program files (x86)". This means you cannot use $(programfiles) to get the path to (32 bit) software. So I need a $(ProgramFiles32) to overcome this in my MSBuild project. I don't want to change the project depending on the os it is running on.

I have a solution that I will post, but maybe there is a easier/better way.

Comment: A lot of the answers are getting a little bit nitpicky on whether a given answer will work on .NET 2.0 and 4.0 -- but I'm not seeing it in the question -- Perhaps you can tell us what version(s) of .NET you plan to target?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 This question was asked in 2008 when .net 4.0 did not exist yet. But generally, I would always prefer a solution which works in any version, to avoid having to make changes when switching version. The accepted answer explains what to use in newer msbuild versions, but also provides a solution for older versions which also works in newer version. So I don't see the point of limiting my question to a specific version.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In MSBuild 4.0+, there's [a `$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx) for it, which you can confidently employ directly (especially if you're prepared to put a `ToolsVersion="4.0"` at the top of the file to guarantee it's going to be available and [Fail Fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) if it's not).

If you're not and need something that can Do The Right Thing even when executed in an MSBuild 2.0 or later environment (i.e., back to VS 2005 environments), the complete solution is:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!--MSBuild 4.0 property-->
    <ProgramFiles32>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)</ProgramFiles32> 
    <!--Use OS env var as a fallback:- 32 bit MSBuild 2.0/3.5 on x64 will use this-->
    <ProgramFiles32 Condition=" '' == '$(ProgramFiles32)'">$(ProgramFiles%28x86%29)</ProgramFiles32>

    <!-- Handle MSBuild 2.0/3.5 running in 64 bit mode - neither of the above env vars are available. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633
       NB this trick (Adding a literal " (x86)" to the 64 bit Program Files path) may or may not work on all versions/locales of Windows -->
    <ProgramFiles32 Condition ="'$(ProgramFiles32)'=='' AND 'AMD64' == '$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)'">$(ProgramFiles) (x86)</ProgramFiles32>

    <!--Catch-all - handles .NET 2.0/3.5 non-AMD64 and .NET 2.0 on x86 -->
    <ProgramFiles32 Condition=" '' == '$(ProgramFiles32)' ">$(ProgramFiles)</ProgramFiles32>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Unfortunately [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) / [polyfill](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/) overriding of the [MSBuild reserved property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx) name `MSBuildProgramFiles32` via either a `<PropertyGroup>` or `<CreateProperty>` is rejected by MSBuild 4.0+ so it can't be made tidier and still support .NET 2.0.

Comment: The progressive enhancement gives me this error on MSBuild 4: `error MSB4004: The "MSBuildProgramFiles32" property is reserved, and cannot be modified.`

Comment: @Wernight Thanks for the catch - removed the progressive enhancement stuff. If your comment disappears, I'll eventually get around to deleting this!

Answer (score 16):

My solution is to look whether "c:\program files (x86)" exists, if it exists, asume this is a 64 bit os. Otherwise use the normal program files directory:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ProgramFiles32 Condition="Exists('$(PROGRAMFILES) (x86)')">$(PROGRAMFILES) (x86)</ProgramFiles32>
  <ProgramFiles32 Condition="$(ProgramFiles32) == ''">$(PROGRAMFILES)</ProgramFiles32>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I can use it like this

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="src\app1" Command='"$(ProgramFiles32)\doxygen\bin\doxygen" Doxyfile' />
```

Comment: This will break horribly on non-english versions of Windows, as program files is not always called program files.

Comment: I think the environment variable %programfiles% points to the program files directory in any language. And at least in German the 32 bits version adds just " (x86)": http://www.tipps-fuer-windows-vista.de/img/Navigation/Navi1.gif Don't know about japanese though.

Comment: You need to check for an environment variable called %ProgramFiles(x86)%. If that exists, then you're on a 64-bit OS, and that's the path you want. If it doesn't exist, then use the path specified by %ProgramFiles%.

Comment: Using Condition="Exists('$(PROGRAMFILES) (x86)')" searches for C:\Program Files (x86) (x86) in the msbuild from .net 4.0.21006

Comment: @Jedidja You mean when one runs the __32 bit__ edition of MSBuild. It works when you use the `Framework64` edition. Confirmed for 4.0.30319 including .NET 4.5 update Beta. Also note that your point, while valid does not prevent the answer from actually 'working', i.e., it does compute `program files (x86)` on MSBuild 2 and 4 x86 and x64 (had been looking to turn my +1 to a -1 based on your info)

Answer (score 12):

In MSBuild 4.0, `$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)` will give you the 32-bit Program Files directory.

Comment: +1 Had written [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346175/use-32bit-program-files-directory-in-msbuild/5650767#5650767) before I saw this so hope no offence is taken at the duplication (the example serves to explain my comment on @JaredPar's answer)

Comment: @Ruben-Bartelink, I like the fallback you mention in your answer. So I chose that as accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

Try `"$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\.."`

Comment: There was meant to be a slash before the double dot. Maybe I mistyped or the web page ate it.

Comment: With the slash it works fine. And it looks cleaner than my solution. This is how I used it:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProgramFiles32>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..</ProgramFiles32>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: -1 This approach doesnt add anything. If MSBuildExtensionsPath32 is available, MSBuildProgramFiles32 will also be available. (Tested - this is definitely not supported on FW 2 MSBuild (inc when specifying a ToolsVersion of 3.5) despite what [this post](http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,7e11f92e-e778-4e69-9441-9a6be3512e71.aspx) suggests)

Comment: This resolves to `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\...` if you are using dotnet.exe

Answer (score 4):

I think a slighly more reliable way is to grab the Environment variable "ProgramFiles(x86)".  In a 64 bit process on Windows this will point to the 32 bit program files directory.  It will be empty on a 32 bit version of windows and I **believe** on a wow64 process

I ran into virtually same problem recently with some PowerShell scripts.  I wrote a blog entry on how a worked around the program files directory issue.  Different language obviously but it may help you out.

http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/21/program-files-i-just-want-the-32-bit-version.aspx

Comment: tried it, but it does not work. "$(PROGRAMFILES(x86))" evaluates to ")". So it looks like it in not possible in msbuild to use an environment variable which includes a ')' character. I did not see anything else in the environment which can be used instead.

Comment: Did you try escaping the ('s?  I'm not a heavy msbuild user so i don't know if this is possible or not

Comment: escaping with a backslash or single quotes did not work. But I'm also not a heavy msbuild user. Probably should ask a new question the escaping...

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't ever get it to evaluate either. I used Wimmel's solution. It works.

Comment: +1; syntax for escaping is $(ProgramFiles%28x86%29) See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228186%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Productized comment in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346175/use-32bit-program-files-directory-in-msbuild/5650767#5650767) (Actually landed here having forgotten the answer!) but if you want to upvote something, please upvote [this one which was there first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346175/use-32bit-program-files-directory-in-msbuild/4380939#4380939)

Comment: @JaredPar: While you're right that a WOW64 process has a `Program Files(x86)` env var and can be used to produce a useful result for 32 bit boxes, unfortunately the `Program Files(x86)` env var is not available in a 64 MSBuild process (2.0 or 4.0-based). (`msbuild /diag` shows the env vars that are present). `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` (`=AMD64`) is the most useful value that is present.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question trying to find a generic way in MSbuild to see if it was a 32- or 64-bit os. In case someone else also find this, I used the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OSBits Condition="$(ProgramW6432) != ''">x64</OSBits>
  <OSBits Condition="$(OSBits) == ''">x32</OSBits>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Apparently `%ProgramW6432%` is only set on 64-bit systems.

Comment: Consider asking the question [as a top-level question] and answering it yourself - it's generally accepted as a Good Thing

Comment: See also the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` (which can be e.g., `AMD64` ) variable for tighter control

Comment: Yeah OP's question can be solved just with $(ProgramW6432). I'm guessing this variable didn't exist when OP posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the 32-bit version of the Visual Studio tools (especially in VS2012, there are like 3 different command prompts you can choose from), $(ProgramFiles) points to "Program Files (x86)"