# visual studio build xcopy command exited with code 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xcopy

I try to run a c# project. However, in builds. It said

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The command "xcopy C:\Project\BusinessObject\bin\Debug\*.* "C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\Reporting Q3 2014\Report Designer\FM_DLLs" /r /y" exited with code 2.
```

I am using Windows 7 32 bit. And I found the "Program files (x86)" does not exist, is this the problem? How should I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: I run it in command prompt. It ask whether the distination is directory of files , I chose Directory.

Comment: _"And I found the "Program files (x86)" does not exist, is this the problem?"_ at least part of it. On a 32 bit system, the "Program files" folder _is_ what on a 64 bit system would be "Program files (x86)".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Build Step Paths Between x86 and x64 in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661523/custom-build-step-paths-between-x86-and-x64-in-visual-studio)