# How to add reference from %programfiles(x86)%?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference

This might be a silly question but I have to add reference to `%programfiles(x86)%` folder (on a 64 bit machine) OR to `%programfiles%` folder (on a 32 bit machine). I also have to set `CopyLocal` to false so that the DLLs are not copied to `bin/debug` folder of my project but always point to the same `%programfiles%` location.

How do I add reference to `%programfiles(x86)%`in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to edit the .csproj manually by opening it in a text editor and changing the HintPath of the DLL that you are referencing. Since I always need to refer location of 32-bit Program Files, I use `$(ProgramFiles)` in HintPath which resolves to `%programfiles%` or `%programfiles(x86)%` automatically.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to "$(ProgramFiles)" is "$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)", which may be slightly more future-proof. See here: [Use 32bit "Program Files" directory in msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346175/use-32bit-program-files-directory-in-msbuild)

Comment: This worked for me when $(ProgramFiles) didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Adding reference to dll in program files looks a bit weird to me. Is this your company's dll or some 3rd party? If it's yours maybe you should reconsider putting it in GAC.

Comment: @Perl Its a third party dll which gets installed in `%programfiles(x86)%\SomeFolder`. I need to refer them from there and not create additional copies of their DLLs in our installer.