# Reliable locate mstest.exe from msbuild

Tags: msbuild, location, mstest

there are some questions about this around here, but none has a valid (for me) answer. The question is:

Is there a way to determine the location of mstest.exe from within a msbuild project, without hardcoding either the path or using the $(VSxxComnTools) or $(VSINSTALLDIR) variables?

Reason for the latter is, because this needs to run on a build server  (non-TFS but Bamboo or TeamCity) that only has the VS Test Agents installed and not a full VS.

Additional Info: Of course, this must also work on every other machine that has msbuild, the c# compiler and mstest installed, because everybody should be able to check out the project from github, call the msbuild and everything should run just smoothly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Ide
```

This assumes you are working with the same version ie 2012 of the skus on all your assets. Ofcourse you can easily create fallbacks to other versions in your project itself.

Refer [Use 32bit "Program Files" directory in msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346175/use-32bit-program-files-directory-in-msbuild).

Answer (score 1):

It's not elegant, but a reliable way to find the latest MSTest.exe installed on a host is

```
<MSTestPath Condition="'$(MSTestPath)'=='' And Exists('$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe')">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe</MSTestPath>
<MSTestPath Condition="'$(MSTestPath)'=='' And Exists('$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 13.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe')">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 13.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe</MSTestPath>
<MSTestPath Condition="'$(MSTestPath)'=='' And Exists('$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe')">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe</MSTestPath>
<MSTestPath Condition="'$(MSTestPath)'=='' And Exists('$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe')">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe</MSTestPath>
<MSTestPath Condition="'$(MSTestPath)'=='' And Exists('$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe')">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe</MSTestPath>
<MSTestPath Condition="'$(MSTestPath)'=='' And Exists('$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe')">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe</MSTestPath>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an machine environment variable that points to it and reference that in msbuild?   So if you added the var MSTEST_HOME you could use $(MSTEST_HOME) in msbuild?

Comment: I could, but that would make it impossible for every one else to just grab the project from i.e. github and build & test it. So this is not a valid option for me.