# How can I get OS Name and Version details in C# on windows mobile 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I find the OS name and os version which is installed in a phone that uses windows phone os.

Comment: Doesn't `Environment.OSVersion.Version` work ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the "friendly" OS Version Name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577634/how-to-get-the-friendly-os-version-name)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try these links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941122%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

you can try this

```
   public MainPage()
   {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetDeviceInfo();    
   }    
   public void GetDeviceInfo()
   {
            long ApplicationMemoryUsage = DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage;
            long PeakMemoryUsage = DeviceStatus.ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage;
            string FirmwareVersion = DeviceStatus.DeviceFirmwareVersion;
            string HardwareVersion = DeviceStatus.DeviceHardwareVersion;
            string Manufacturer = DeviceStatus.DeviceManufacturer;
            string DeviceName = DeviceStatus.DeviceName;
            long TotalMemory = DeviceStatus.DeviceTotalMemory;
            string OSVersion = Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString(); ;
            PowerSource powerSource = DeviceStatus.PowerSource;
            AddToList("Memory Usage :" + ApplicationMemoryUsage);
            AddToList("Peak Memory Usage :" + PeakMemoryUsage);
            AddToList("Firmware Version :" + FirmwareVersion);
            AddToList("Hardware Version :" + HardwareVersion);
            AddToList("Manufacturer :" + Manufacturer);
            AddToList("Total Memory :" + TotalMemory);
            AddToList("Power Source:" + powerSource.ToString());
            AddToList("Operating System: Windows Phone " + OSVersion.ToString());

   }    
   public void AddToList(string Property)
   {
            lstboxDeviceInfo.Items.Add(Property);
   }
```

take a look at here [for more info](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/07/retreive-the-device-information-from-windows-phone/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `DeviceStatus` class.

Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941122%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) about it.

**Added** - after first comment

Check out [`System.Environment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

```
System.Environment.OSVersion
```

Comment: Here we get the details of the hardware. I need the name of OS.  like , Microsoft Windows CE 7.10.7720

Comment: Aah, my apologies. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: @NelsonTJoseph I have edited my answer would you pls try that.

Comment: @Nelson T Joseph - You've just said that you didn't want to use DeviceStatus then accepted the answer that uses DeviceStatus lol...

Answer (score 1):

I think the version should be grabbed from `Environment.OSVersion.Version` and i think you will have to compare them to list of operating systems applicable

- Windows Mobile 6              5.2
- Wndows Mobile 5.0             5.1
- Windows  Mobile 2003 SE   4.21
  ....

I found this [article](http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/77) which might help in determing the platform

Answer (score 0):

What about using

`Environment.OSVersion`

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx)