# Get windows operating system version in windows phone8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to get Operating System name and version of windows phone using C#. I am trying `System.Environment.OSVersion` but it says `OSVersion` not found in `System.Environment`

Comment: It should work. Here is similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472010/how-can-i-get-os-name-and-version-details-in-c-sharp-on-windows-mobile-7
Maybe it would help you

Comment: Short answer: you can't and they don't want you to because they didn't want developers to target specific versions of 8.x.  It has nothing at all to do with now many versions exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Environment.OSVersion` will not work in Windows 8.1, because win 8.1 has many several versions. I think they will fix this bug when release newer versions.

Comment: this will help you to get the firmware version  Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation deviceInfo = new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation();
    var firmwareVersion = deviceInfo.SystemFirmwareVersion;

Comment: I am working on windows phone 8.0