# How to detect Windows 8 Operating system using C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have to detect Windows 8 Operating system in my C# Windows Application and do some settings.   I know we can detect Windows 7 using `Environment.OSVersion`, but how can windows 8 be detected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well have you tried using Environment.OSVersion and checked what it produces on Windows 8?

Comment: It Prints Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0

Comment: So can't you use that?

Comment: Thanks. Good thought. I will use that

Comment: Have you considered which answer does work for you? it would be nice if you've accepted that answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
Version win8version = new Version(6, 2, 9200, 0);

if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT &&
    Environment.OSVersion.Version >= win8version)
{
    // its win8 or higher.
}
```

### Update for windows 8.1 and higher:

Okay guys, it seems to me that this piece of code has been marked as deprecated by Microsoft itself. I leave a [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885961/558018) so you could read more about it.

*In short, it says:*

For windows 8 and higher, there always will be the same version number of **(6, 2, 9200, 0)**. And rather than looking for Windows version, go look for the actual feature which existance you are trying to resolve.

Comment: In my Windows Store app OSVersion is not found, Environment.OSVersion is not found, PlatformID is not found. So for Windows Store apps this would not work. Bad.

Comment: @Tertium there is no Windows Store tag in the question.

Comment: The OSVersion.Platform should say Environment.OSVersion.Platform

Comment: Please watch out for this on Windows 10: it returns the same result as Windows 8

Comment: @superjos which is (6, 2, 9200, 0)?

Comment: @AgentFire yes, that's it

Answer (score 13):

Windows 8 or more recent:

```
bool IsWindows8OrNewer()
{
    var os = Environment.OSVersion;
    return os.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT && 
           (os.Version.Major > 6 || (os.Version.Major == 6 && os.Version.Minor >= 2));
}
```

Comment: Should actually be:

return os.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT &&
   (os.Version.Major > 6 || (os.Version.Major == 6 && os.Version.Minor >= 2));

Comment: Why dont just use the `> or < or == or <= etc` operators of `Version` struct?

Comment: Because I wasn't aware of these when I wrote the answer, and shortly after you provided an answer using these. Your answer is better but I left mine as an alternative option.

Answer (score 3):

Check the answer to the following question: [How to get the "friendly" OS Version Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577634/how-to-get-the-friendly-os-version-name)

Quoted answer:

> You can use WMI to get the product name ("Microsoft® Windows Server® 2008 Enterprise "):

```
using System.Management;
var name = (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>() select x.GetPropertyValue("Caption")).First();
return name != null ? name.ToString() : "Unknown";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but i don't want to use WMI.

Answer (score 2):

Start by declaring a struct as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct OsVersionInfoEx
{
    public int dwOSVersionInfoSize;
    public uint dwMajorVersion;
    public uint dwMinorVersion;
    public uint dwBuildNumber;
    public uint dwPlatformId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string szCSDVersion;
    public UInt16 wServicePackMajor;
    public UInt16 wServicePackMinor;
    public UInt16 wSuiteMask;
    public byte wProductType;
    public byte wReserved;
}
```

You will need this using statement:

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

At the top of your relevant class, declare:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "GetVersionEx")]
    static extern bool GetVersionEx(ref OsVersionInfoEx osVersionInfoEx);
```

Now call the code as follows:

```
        const int VER_NT_WORKSTATION = 1;
        var osInfoEx = new OsVersionInfoEx();
        osInfoEx.dwOSVersionInfoSize = Marshal.SizeOf(osInfoEx);
        try
        {
            if (!GetVersionEx(ref osInfoEx))
            {
                throw(new Exception("Could not determine OS Version"));

            }
            if (osInfoEx.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osInfoEx.dwMinorVersion == 2 
                && osInfoEx.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
                MessageBox.Show("You've Got windows 8");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Overly complicated compared to the in-built .Net API. :)

Comment: This is actually the only way to detect for Win8 AND differentiate between Standard/Workstation and Server version.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is correct as I can only check on the version of windows 8 I have.

```
 int major = Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major;
 int minor = Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor;

if ((major >= 6) && (minor >= 2))
{
    //do work here
}
```

Comment: What will happen for major = 7 and minor = 0?

Comment: Better to just get the version and substring(Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString().Substring(0,3)), then compare to the version table(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You can change the operators as needed but from what I posted it will accept anything above windows 8 / server 2012. As you can see from the MSDN link posted above they are currently only 6.2.x.x

Comment: Why not use `Version.CompareTo`? `if( Environment.OSVersion.Version.CompareTo( new Version(6, 2) ) > 0 ) { /* win8 or later */ }`

Comment: Seems like a hybrid of Asik's and @AngentFire's solutions is what is needed. No point in trying to re-invent the >= operator that the Version class already implements. Always surprising how simple it is to get things like that wrong when you try to over-optimize.

Comment: This answer is very wrong. The number of upvotes is truly remarkable.