# How can I detect if my app is running on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10

I'm looking for a means to detect if my C# app is running on Windows 10.

I had hoped that `Environment.OSVersion` would do the trick, but this seems to return a `Version` of `6.3.9600.0` on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

Other solutions such as [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sample-to-demonstrate-how-495e69db) don't seem to distinguish between Windows 8 and Windows 10 either.

Any suggestions?

---

Why do I need to do this?

Because I'm using a WinForms WebBrowser control to host an OAuth page that crashes and burns in older IE versions.

By default, the WebBrowser control emulates IE7. Using a Registry key, you can tell it to emulate the latest version of IE that is installed on the host PC. However, the [value that worked](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) up to Windows 8.1 (and pre-releases of Windows 10) does not work in the final version of Windows 10.

Comment: Did you [manifest the app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows 10?

Comment: Do you run your program using compatibility mode ?

Comment: There are other way to get this information, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331826/get-os-version-friendly-name-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Graffito - My app doesn't run in compatibility mode.

Comment: Have you tried `12000` or `12001` for `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you look at registry you will found environment name:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName
```

For example my product name is `Windows 10 Home`:

[image: Registry]

With this code you get if it Windows 10:

```
 static bool IsWindows10()
 {
     var reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");

     string productName = (string)reg.GetValue("ProductName");

     return productName.StartsWith("Windows 10");
 }
```

Note: Add `using Microsoft.Win32;` to your usings.

Comment: @Rawling - In my scenario this is an old-skool WinForms app, installed via ClickOnce

Comment: @RichardEverett Fair point! Kids these days and their "apps", I don't know... :)

Comment: @MitatKoyuncu Yes thanks, your approach worked nicely!

Comment: Using `StartsWith` will be incorrect on Windows 100.

Comment: @Boann which Windows version product name is "Windows 100"?

Comment: @MitatKoyuncu It doesn't exist yet. I'm just saying (mostly jokingly) that it's not future proof. They had to skip Windows 9 because of all the code that uses `StartsWith("Windows 9")` to detect Windows 95 and 98.

Comment: @Boann for example for control os version is Windows 9 or not we can split product name and get second part and control if it is 9 or not.  We can customise this method by this way.

Comment: ... no, don't do this.

Comment: Much safer to check the actual _numeric_ version value there, in  `CurrentMajorVersionNumber`, as Spiralis suggested in their answer. And if the value doesn't exist, well, you can safely assume it's not Win10 ;)

Answer (score 42):

**Answer**

Use `Environment.OSVersion` and add an application manifest file with relevant `supportedOS` elements uncommented.

e.g. add this under <asmv1:assembly>

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
        <!-- Windows 10 --> 
        <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
        <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
        <!-- Windows Vista -->
        <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
        <!-- Windows 7 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
        <!-- Windows 8 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    </application> 
</compatibility>
```

**Reason**

I don't like the answer from @Mitat Koyuncu  because is uses the registry unnecessarily and as mentioned in the comments uses unreliable string parsing.

I also don't like the answer from @sstan because it uses third party code and it needs the application manifest anyway.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725492(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **Windows 10:  VerifyVersionInfo** returns false when called by
>    applications that do not have a compatibility manifest for Windows 8.1
>    or Windows 10 if the lpVersionInfo parameter is set so that it
>    specifies Windows 8.1 or Windows 10, even when the current operating
>    system version is Windows 8.1 or Windows 10. Specifically,
>    **VerifyVersionInfo** has the following behavior:
>
> • If the application has no manifest, **VerifyVersionInfo** behaves as if the operation system version is Windows 8 (6.2).
>
> • If the application has a manifest that contains the GUID that corresponds to Windows 8.1, **VerifyVersionInfo** behaves as if the operation system version is Windows 8.1 (6.3).
>
> • If the application has a manifest that contains the GUID that corresponds
>   to Windows 10, **VerifyVersionInfo** behaves as if the operation system
>   version is Windows 10 (10.0).

The reason is because VerifyVersionInfo is deprecated in Windows 10.

I have tested on Windows 10 and indeed `Environment.OSVersion` works exactly as expected when the app.Manifest contains the relevant GUID as above. That is most likely why they did not change or deprecate it from .Net Framework.

Comment: This is the correct, official, approach. I would like to point out to others that when testing with your `app.manifest`, make sure it is actually in your output folder. When in the debug configuration, mine wasn't copied to `bin/Debug`. Thought the `app.manifest` wasn't working until I tried release and dug a little further.

Comment: Worked for me. Was showing NT version 6.2 until I added the above to the app.manifest.

Comment: Only thing missing in this question is a usage example.

Comment: This is the correct answer not the accepted one, **Environment.OSVersion** uses **GetVersion** and **GetVersionEx** APIs. From MSDN: 

The behavior of the **GetVersionEx** API has changed in the value it will return for the operating system version. The value returned by the GetVersionEx function now depends on how the application is manifested. Applications not manifested for Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 will return the Windows 8 OS version value (6.2).

Comment: BTW Microsoft warns about the GetVersionEx API: **GetVersionEx** may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use the Version Helper functions.

Answer (score 16):

Under the hood, [Environment.OSVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx) uses the [GetVersionEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx), which has been deprecated.  The documentation warns about the behavior you observed:

> Applications not manifested for Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 will return the Windows 8 OS version value (6.2).

The documentation goes on to recommend:

> Identifying the current operating system is usually not the best way to determine whether a particular operating system feature is present. This is because the operating system may have had new features added in a redistributable DLL. Rather than using **GetVersionEx** to determine the operating system platform or version number, test for the presence of the feature itself.

If the above recommendation is not appropriate for your case, and you really want to check the actual running OS version, then the documentation also provides a hint about this:

> To compare the current system version to a required version, use the **VerifyVersionInfo** function instead of using **GetVersionEx** to perform the comparison yourself.

The following article has posted a working solution using the **VerifyVersionInfo** function: [Version Helper API for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/707502/Version-Helper-API-for-NET).

Giving full credit to the author of that article, the following code snippet should provide the behavior you are looking for:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(6, 3, 0)); // Plug in appropriate values.
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct OsVersionInfoEx
    {
        public uint OSVersionInfoSize;
        public uint MajorVersion;
        public uint MinorVersion;
        public uint BuildNumber;
        public uint PlatformId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string CSDVersion;
        public ushort ServicePackMajor;
        public ushort ServicePackMinor;
        public ushort SuiteMask;
        public byte ProductType;
        public byte Reserved;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern ulong VerSetConditionMask(ulong dwlConditionMask,
       uint dwTypeBitMask, byte dwConditionMask);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool VerifyVersionInfo(
        [In] ref OsVersionInfoEx lpVersionInfo,
        uint dwTypeMask, ulong dwlConditionMask);

    static bool IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(
        uint majorVersion, uint minorVersion, ushort servicePackMajor)
    {
        OsVersionInfoEx osvi = new OsVersionInfoEx();
        osvi.OSVersionInfoSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(osvi);
        osvi.MajorVersion = majorVersion;
        osvi.MinorVersion = minorVersion;
        osvi.ServicePackMajor = servicePackMajor;
        // These constants initialized with corresponding definitions in
        // winnt.h (part of Windows SDK)
        const uint VER_MINORVERSION = 0x0000001;
        const uint VER_MAJORVERSION = 0x0000002;
        const uint VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR = 0x0000020;
        const byte VER_GREATER_EQUAL = 3;
        ulong versionOrGreaterMask = VerSetConditionMask(
            VerSetConditionMask(
                VerSetConditionMask(
                    0, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
                VER_MINORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
            VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
        uint versionOrGreaterTypeMask = VER_MAJORVERSION |
            VER_MINORVERSION | VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR;
        return VerifyVersionInfo(ref osvi, versionOrGreaterTypeMask,
            versionOrGreaterMask);
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: I don't have Windows 10 yet, so I haven't tested the code on Windows 10.*

Comment: From MSDN: "In Windows 10, the VerifyVersionInfo function has also been deprecated. While you can still call the deprecated functions, if your application does not specifically target Windows 8.1 or Windows 10, you will get Windows 8 version (6.2.0.0). "

Comment: Not working, still returning 6.2 for Win10!
"Windows 10: VerifyVersionInfo returns false when called...."

Answer (score 7):

I suggest using the registry to find the values you want. Microsoft has changed the way Windows 10 is listed in the registry so the code needs to adapt for that.

Here is the code I uses, that correctly identifies Windows 10 as well:

```
namespace Inspection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Static class that adds convenient methods for getting information on the running computers basic hardware and os setup.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ComputerInfo
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns the Windows major version number for this computer.
        /// </summary>
        public static uint WinMajorVersion
        {
            get
            {
                dynamic major;
                // The 'CurrentMajorVersionNumber' string value in the CurrentVersion key is new for Windows 10, 
                // and will most likely (hopefully) be there for some time before MS decides to change this - again...
                if (TryGetRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentMajorVersionNumber", out major))
                {
                    return (uint) major;
                }

                // When the 'CurrentMajorVersionNumber' value is not present we fallback to reading the previous key used for this: 'CurrentVersion'
                dynamic version;
                if (!TryGetRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentVersion", out version))
                    return 0;

                var versionParts = ((string) version).Split('.');
                if (versionParts.Length != 2) return 0;
                uint majorAsUInt;
                return uint.TryParse(versionParts[0], out majorAsUInt) ? majorAsUInt : 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns the Windows minor version number for this computer.
        /// </summary>
        public static uint WinMinorVersion
        {
            get
            {
                dynamic minor;
                // The 'CurrentMinorVersionNumber' string value in the CurrentVersion key is new for Windows 10, 
                // and will most likely (hopefully) be there for some time before MS decides to change this - again...
                if (TryGetRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentMinorVersionNumber",
                    out minor))
                {
                    return (uint) minor;
                }

                // When the 'CurrentMinorVersionNumber' value is not present we fallback to reading the previous key used for this: 'CurrentVersion'
                dynamic version;
                if (!TryGetRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentVersion", out version))
                    return 0;

                var versionParts = ((string) version).Split('.');
                if (versionParts.Length != 2) return 0;
                uint minorAsUInt;
                return uint.TryParse(versionParts[1], out minorAsUInt) ? minorAsUInt : 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns whether or not the current computer is a server or not.
        /// </summary>
        public static uint IsServer
        {
            get
            {
                dynamic installationType;
                if (TryGetRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "InstallationType",
                    out installationType))
                {
                    return (uint) (installationType.Equals("Client") ? 0 : 1);
                }

                return 0;
            }
        }

        private static bool TryGetRegistryKey(string path, string key, out dynamic value)
        {
            value = null;
            try
            {
                var rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path);
                if (rk == null) return false;
                value = rk.GetValue(key);
                return value != null;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! This did the job for me. Didn't bother checking anything else than the 'CurrentMajorVersionNumber' though; the app only needed to know if it was running on Win10 or not. If the registry key doesn't exist because it's an older version, well, mission accomplished I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use the Version Helper functions?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx

> IsWindows10OrGreater
>
> Indicates if the current OS version matches, or is greater than, the
>   Windows 10 version. For Windows 10, IsWindows10OrGreater returns false
>   unless the application contains a manifest that includes a
>   compatibility section that contains the GUID that designates Windows
>   10.

and add the GUIDs:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
string subKey = @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion";
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine;
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey skey = key.OpenSubKey(subKey);

string name = skey.GetValue("ProductName").ToString();
```

and then you can just use an if clause:

```
if(name.Contains("Windows 10"))
{
    //... procedures
}
else
{
   //... procedures
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried below? [You need to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisulaBasic` dll]

```
new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().OSFullName
```

On my machine it gives, *Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate*

Comment: this is depreciated in windows 10.

Comment: @Claies, No idea about that but that sucks then :)

Comment: Also...I'd rather avoid adding a VisualBasic reference to my C# project.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using the Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build.

For instance, to check whether the app is running under Windows 11, use the following in C#

Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build >= 22000

To check, if running under under Windows 10, you can check that to be between [10240 and 19045]

The list of Windows 10 versions could be found at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/release-information