# How can I get the real OS version in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Since .NET 4 and Windows 8 or greater platforms it's quite uncertain to get the OS version where your program is ran.

For instance, running in a Windows 10, if my project has a Windows 8 DLL then the `Environment.OSVersion.Version` returns `6.2.9200.0` which is Windows 8 and not Windows 10.

This behaviour is explained in this question ([crono](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848975/crono)'s answer): [Windows version in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737985/windows-version-in-c-sharp)

So my question is the following: How can we detect for sure (and staying in a  .NET way in order to be able to use it on non-Windows platforms) the OS version where our application is running?

Link to MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I was going to post an answer about [manifesting your application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows 10 so that `Environment.OSVersion.Version` would return the right value (I recently had to do this to get the software I work on to detect Windows 10), but I'm not sure it would help you if you are on a non-Windows platform. I did a bit of searching and it seems that Mono, for instance, seems to have problems listening to the `app.manifest` file.

Comment: That's what I've found about the matter. However the one that has made the program needs to recompile it if there is a Windows 10.1 or even 11 in order to his app to detect correctly the version. And, considering the lifecycle of an App it can be wrong to run an old version of your app in such Windows when it was thought for previous versions just because OsVersion returns the last version allowed per the manifest. Not sure that I'm clear ... That decision of Microsoft is quite disturbing ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If using other platforms than windows is not a concern, you can use [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) WMI class.

> [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) represents a Windows-based operating system
>   installed on a computer

```
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Management;
```

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem";
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
var info = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();
var caption = info.Properties["Caption"].Value.ToString();
var version = info.Properties["Version"].Value.ToString();
var spMajorVersion = info.Properties["ServicePackMajorVersion"].Value.ToString();
var spMinorVersion = info.Properties["ServicePackMinorVersion"].Value.ToString();
```

Remember to add a reference to `System.Management.dll`.

**Note:**

- If you want to use Windows API Functions for this purpose, pay attention that [`GetVersionEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexa?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)  may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use the [Version Helper functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/version-helper-apis?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).
- Starting with Windows 8, the [`Environment.OSVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.osversion?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property returns the same major and minor version numbers for all Windows platforms. Therefore, we do not recommend that you retrieve the value of this property to determine the operating system version.
- You may want to take a look at [Mono FAQ - How to detect the execution platform?](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/technical/#how-to-detect-the-execution-platform)

Comment: Quite interesting ... however : Is there a method that doesn't rely on windows specific technology ?

Comment: Take a look at this Mono FAQ: [How to detect the execution platform?](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/technical/#how-to-detect-the-execution-platform)

Comment: Thank you : A mix between your solution and this page is what I've been looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear that you fixed it :)

Comment: works but why loop over `ManagementObject`? is there a possibility of more than 1? if not why not just `searcher.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault()` ?

Comment: @wal Thank you for your feedback, I enhanced the answer based on your comment. Probably I was going to write the answer without dependency to `System.Linq`, but it's better now :)