# How to recognize Windows OS version?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio-2010, operating-system

I am developing .NET 4 WPF application and this application should be able to export data to Excel xls worksheet. However I need to resolve at runtime which version it is running on since there are still computers with Windows XP and Office 97/2000 on them.

I wasn't able to export xls trough my application on Windows XP, Office 97/2000 because we don't own Office Interop libraries, versions 7, 8, or 9.

Therefore I will export to CSV on Windows XP and xls on Windows 7 and Windows 10.

I tried this code snippet but I am unsure if it is enough info to recognize if it is Win XP, 7 or 10.

```
 public static string getOSVersion()
 {
      return Environment.OSVersion.ToString() + ", " + Environment.Version;
 }
```

I am getting this on Windows 10:

```
 Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0, 4.0.30319.42000
```

Is this enough information or is there a better way to recognize Windows OS Name?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32415824/7405620) answer can help you
.

Comment: You can export to Excel without having the Excel installed (no Interop needed). See e.g. https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Environment.Version` will retrieve the Version of the .NET Framework used to execute your code, so this will not help you.

The `System.Environment.OSVersion` object (OperatingSystem class) is indeed the correct way to get the Windows version. You should however do something like this:

```
public static bool IsWindowsCurrentGen()
{
  if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

This will return `true` for everything above (including) Windows Vista.

For a "full" reference table see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-version-in-net). Note, that it would be better from my point of view, to detect the installed Excel version rather than the OS version.