# My project can't detect if I'm using Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, version, environment

I have a `app.manifest` with the Windows 10 `GUID` and even with that, my .net 4.0 project can't detect my current Windows version. (10.0.10586)

It detects as `6.2.9200`, the W8 version, I believe.

I'm using `Environment.OSVersion.Version` inside a library project that also has a `app.manifest`, both with all the `GUID's.

How can I detect the system's version without reading from a registry or a external dll?

### Edit

Oh, it looks like the `Evironment.OSVersion` uses `GetVersionEx` and it's deprecated. I wonder with .net 4.5 uses the same method.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737985/windows-version-in-c-sharp and this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Someone [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a62b5e39-40c9-45c8-8e90-3fa37b71cddf/windows-10-version-629200?forum=WinPreview2014General) used WMI to get the correct version.

Comment: @Aybe My project contains the `app.manifest` with all the `GUID`'s.

Comment: @Quantic using WMI to get that info, looks quite a punch to kill a mosquito.