# C# determine OS is Windows 7 or WIndows Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, windows, version

I am using .NET framework 3.5 version, and the program has to detect all the Windows versions(including Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012).

The problem is how can I determine the OS in below situations?

- Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 Version number both are 6.0.
- Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 Version number both are 6.1.
- Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 Version number both are 6.2.

I have found the below code but I can't use because I'm using .NET Framework 3.5.

```
var name = (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>()
                  select x.GetPropertyValue("Caption")).FirstOrDefault();
return name != null ? name.ToString() : "Unknown";
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I do not know your specific need to determine the OS version.  That said, as a general rule, you should test for whether functionality is present and not the OS version.  Furthermore, almost all of the functionality between the client and server versions of Windows are the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577634/how-to-get-the-friendly-os-version-name

Comment: The code above works fine in .NET 3.5. Make sure System.Linq is in your using clause and that you add a reference to System.Management.dll.

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.environment?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the problem with that code is that it uses LINQ. You can still use WMI to check it, just don't use LINQ. I also think it's better to check the `ProductType` rather than `Caption`.

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"))
{
    foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in searcher.Get())
    {
        uint productType = (uint)managementObject.GetPropertyValue("ProductType");
        // productType will be 1 for workstation, 2 for domain controller,
        // 3 for normal server
    }
}
```

Then just check version number to determine actual OS version.

Another way is to use [registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152078) and check the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions\ProductType`. This will have values WinNT, ServerNT or LanmanNT to mark the same options as the WMI code.

Comment: Thank you! .NET framework 3.5 doesn't support LINQ, and your solution is perfect. Here is another problem, how can I fouind `ManagementObjectSearcher` and`ManagementObject` class? I have using `System.Management`.

Comment: They are in System.Management https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher%28v=vs.90%29.aspx, make sure you have the assembly reference in place

Comment: I have add  System.Management to reference, it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get information from **registry file**. It works perfectly from .net 3.0 and above.

```
String loc= @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion";
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey skey = key.OpenSubKey(loc);
Console.WriteLine("OS Name: {0}", skey.GetValue("ProductName"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day

Maybe someone reach this question on 2022, so it is worth noting that you can use the "Environment" Class to get all kind of info about de computer you are running your application.

In my code, and making comparation with the different build numbers (https://www.gaijin.at/en/infos/windows-version-numbers) I am able to discriminate if running in Windows 7, 10 or 11.

Here's a snippet:

```
System.Environment ('or using System;')

if (System.Environment.Version.Build> 9200) { 'do something'}
```

Regards
PD: Seems that has been supported for a long time... https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.environment?view=net-6.0