# Is there a Windows API call that will tell me if I'm running on a 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a Windows API call that will tell me if I'm running on a 64-bit OS?  I have some legacy c++ code that makes a call to GetVersionEx to fill in a OSVERSIONINFO structure, but that only tells me (AFAIK) the OS (Vista, V7, etc.), but not the processing architecture.  I can hack around this by simply looking for the existence of "C:\Program Files (x86)...", but this seems ugly.  I'm sure there must be an API to return this info.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to know? Is it not something that can't be done if pre-compiler directives?

Comment: @Rowland: That cannot be done after a program has been released. Besides, a 64-bit OS is significantly different from a 32-bit at the hardware layers; i.e. a 32-bit driver installer should detect the 'bitness' of the host OS before installing.

Comment: I thought WOW handled the talking to drivers et al - I would assume that installation of said drivers would be done with an installation framework; just curiosity with the the intention of understanding *why* this would need to be done...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`IsWow64Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28VS.85%29.aspx) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Just be aware that this function always returns false if run from a 64-bit application (because 64-bit apps aren't running in WoW64 mode).

Comment: Absolutely. (Of course, detecting whether the current application is a 64-bit application could be done at compile-time, e.g. via `_M_X64` in msvc)

Answer (score 4):

`GetNativeSystemInfo()`

Answer (score 1):

I found this post that seems to provide a good answer: [Detect whether current Windows version is 32 bit or 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601089/detect-whether-current-windows-version-is-32-bit-or-64-bit)

I don't know why it didn't come up when I search Stack Overflow before posting.

Incidentally, the best solution for me is to simply check for the ProgramW6432 environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty straight-forward. If you are compiling for 64-bit, you already know that you are running on a 64-bit version of Windows. So you only need to call [IsWow64Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139.aspx) when compiling for 32-bit. The following implementation returns `true`, if it is running on a 64-bit version of Windows:

```
bool Is64BitPlatform() {
    #if defined(_WIN64)
        return true;  // 64-bit code implies a 64-bit OS
    #elif defined(_WIN32)
        // 32-bit code runs on a 64-bit OS, if IsWow64Process returns TRUE
        BOOL f = FALSE;
        return ::IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &f) && f;
    #else
        #error Unexpected platform.
    #endif
}
```

This answers the question you asked. The answer to the question you should have asked instead was posted in the [response by Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1646494/1889329) already: Simply call [GetNativeSystemInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340.aspx).