# Perl returns MSWin32 whereas my laptop is 64-bit

Tags: perl, windows-7, operating-system, windows-7-x64, system-calls

```
print "$^O\n";
```

returns

```
MSWin32
```

However, my laptop is 64-bit.  Any idea if the Perl system call retrieves wrong data (by its or Windows' bug) or is it as designed?

Comment: You'll probably find this interesting as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030280/329921

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Win32 is just the standard Windows API. This has little connection to 32-bit/64-bit processors or OS variants.

From `perldoc -v $^O`:

> In Windows platforms, $^O is not very helpful: since it is always "MSWin32", it doesn't tell the difference between 95/98/ME/NT/2000/XP/CE/.NET.  Use Win32::GetOSName() or Win32::GetOSVersion() (see Win32 and perlport) to distinguish between the variants.

On my system, it isn't very helpful either; returning just a plain `linux` ;-)

Comment: i only need to differentiate whether the OS is Win or Linux so Win32 is fine (no difference in my script between 32 and 64 bit archs) but it just got my attention so i wanted to ask.  i don't really need `Win32::GetOSName()` functionally, was just curious

Answer (score 3):

`$^O` is always `MSWin32` on Windows.

If you want to know more about the system on which `perl` runs, you can use

```
use Win32;
print Win32::GetOSDisplayName(), "\n";
print Win32::GetOSName(), "\n";
print Win32::GetOSVersion(), "\n";
```

If you want to know the architecture for which `perl` was built, you can use

```
use Config qw( $Config );
print "$Config{archname}\n";
```

If you want to know the size of integers, you can use

```
use Config qw( $Config );
print $Config{ivsize}*8, " bits\n";
```