# How to recode Windows XP %PROGRAMFILES% for Windows XP and later

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cmd

How should I recode a Windows XP cmd batch file containing the commands below to work also on later Windows where the two .exes *may* be in **Program Files (x86)**?

```
start "GW" /WAIT "%PROGRAMFILES%\GoldWave\GoldWave.exe" [...arguments...]
start "BC" /WAIT "%PROGRAMFILES%\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe" [...arguments...]
```

This fails:

```
PATH=%PATH%;%PROGRAMFILES%;%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%
...
start "GW" /WAIT "GoldWave\GoldWave.exe" [...arguments...]
start "BC" /WAIT "Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe" [...arguments...]
```

This succeeds but is clumsy:

```
PATH=%PATH%;%PROGRAMFILES%\Goldwave;%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Goldwave;%PROGRAMFILES%\Beyond Compare 3;%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Beyond Compare 3%
...
start "GW" /WAIT "GoldWave.exe" [...arguments...]
start "BC" /WAIT "BCompare.exe" [...arguments...]
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601089/detect-whether-current-windows-version-is-32-bit-or-64-bit) could be of help.

Comment: " The default on English-language systems is C:\Program Files. In 64-bit editions of Windows (XP, 2003, Vista), there are also %ProgramFiles(x86)% which defaults to C:\Program Files (x86) and %ProgramW6432% which defaults to C:\Program Files. The %ProgramFiles% itself depends on whether the process requesting the environment variable is itself 32-bit or 64-bit " --- so for the solution below I should use %ProgramW6432% -- thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first check to see if `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` has a value. If it does, the programs you are looking for should be found in that directory:

```
SETLOCAL
SET PROGRAMFILESINUSE=%ProgramFiles%
IF NOT "%ProgramFiles(x86)%"=="" SET PROGRAMFILESINUSE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
START "GW" /WAIT "%PROGRAMFILESINUSE%\GoldWave\GoldWave.exe"
```

Or, you could make it a little more involved and have it actually check where the file you are looking for exists:

```
SETLOCAL
SET PROGRAMDIRECTORY=
SET RELATIVEFILEPATH=GoldWave\Goldwave.exe
CALL :CHECKFORPROGRAM "%RELATIVEFILEPATH%" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
CALL :CHECKFORPROGRAM "%RELATIVEFILEPATH%" "%ProgramFiles%"
IF "%PROGRAMDIRECTORY%"=="" GOTO :NOTFOUND
ECHO Found at %PROGRAMDIRECTORY%\%RELATIVEFILEPATH%
GOTO :EOF
:CHECKFORPROGRAM
IF NOT "%PROGRAMDIRECTORY%"=="" GOTO :EOF
IF EXIST "%~2\%~1" SET PROGRAMDIRECTORY=%~2
GOTO :EOF
:NOTFOUND
ECHO %RELATIVEFILEPATH% not found
GOTO :EOF
```