# How can I discover whether my CPU is 32 or 64 bits?

Tags: language-agnostic, processor

How do I find out if my processor is 32 bit or 64 bit (in your language of choice)? I want to know this for both Intel and AMD processors.

Comment: You'll have to at least provide the language you're trying to find this information in

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question.

Comment: Nope not a programming question. should be closed

Comment: Since the top answer is actually a programming-related one, I thought I'd take the opportunity to make the question more explicitly so (and vote to re-open). That answer is quite handy to know.

Comment: I want it opened too. This is actually quite interesting!

Comment: The question isn't as clear as it should be, but it looks to me like how a program ("in your language of choice") can find what it's running on.  I'd call that a programming question.  I'd swear it's a dupe, but I don't see anything in the "Relate" sidebar.

Comment: Which operating system are we talking about here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Windows, C/C++:

```
#include <windows.h>

SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo, *lpInfo;
lpInfo = &sysInfo;
::GetSystemInfo(lpInfo);
switch (lpInfo->wProcessorArchitecture) {
case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64:
case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64:
    // 64 bit
    break;
case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL:
    // 32 bit
    break;
case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_UNKNOWN:
default:
    // something else
    break;
}
```

Comment: Can you specify which language this is (yes, *I* know but others may not) and any other requirements (e.g., header files)?

Comment: Or, for that matter, what OS?  Will this work on my Mac Mini, my Linux boxes, and my Windows XP and Vista systems?

Comment: Bah - can't edit... but so *need* to add the 'default:' to that switch... :-)

Answer (score 9):

C#, OS agnostic

```
sizeof(IntPtr) == 4 ? "32-bit" : "64-bit"
```

This is somewhat crude but basically tells you whether the CLR is running as 32-bit or 64-bit, which is more likely what you would need to know. The CLR can run as 32-bit on a 64-bit processor, for example.

For more information, see here: [How to detect Windows 64-bit platform with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Answer (score 4):

The tricky bit here is you might have a 64 bit CPU but a 32 bit OS. If you care about that case it is going to require an asm stub to interrogate the CPU. If not, you can ask the OS easily.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET you can differentiate x86 from x64 by looking at the Size property of the IntPtr structure. The [IntPtr.Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.size(vs.71).aspx) property is returned in bytes, 8 bits per byte so it is equal to 4 on a 32-bit CPU and 8 on a 64-bit CPU. Since we talk about 32-bit and 64-bit processors rather than 4-byte or 8-byte processors, I like to do the comparison in bits which makes it more clear what is going on.

C#

```
if( IntPtr.Size * 8 == 64 )
{
    //x64 code
}
```

PowerShell

```
if( [IntPtr]::Size * 8 -eq 64 )
{
    #x64 code 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

VBScript, Windows:

```
Const PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_X86 = 0
Const PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64 = 6
Const PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_X64 = 9

strComputer = "."

Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
    "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessors = oWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")

For Each oProcessor In colProcessors
  Select Case oProcessor.Architecture
    Case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_X86
      ' 32-bit
    Case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_X64, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64
      ' 64-bit
    Case Else
      ' other
  End Select
Next
```

Another possible solution for Windows Script Host, this time in JScript and using the PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE environment variable:

```
var oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var oEnv = oShell.Environment("System");
switch (oEnv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE").toLowerCase())
{
  case "x86":
    // 32-bit
  case "amd64":
    // 64-bit
  default:
    // other
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python :

```
In [10]: import platform
In [11]: platform.architecture()
Out[11]: ('32bit', 'ELF')
```

As usual, pretty neat. But I'm pretty sure these functions return the platform where the exec has been built, not the the platforms it running on. There is still a small chance that some geek is running a 32 bits version on a 64 bits computer.

You can have some more infos like :

```
In [13]: platform.system()
Out[13]: 'Linux'

In [19]: platform.uname()
Out[19]: 
('Linux',
 'asus-u6',
 '2.6.28-11-generic',
 '#42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 17 01:57:59 UTC 2009',
 'i686',
 '')
```

ETC.

This looks more like live data :-)

Comment: I am that geek.  64bit python exists, but its difficult to get prebuilt modules for that architecture, and almost as hard to get working ones compiled locally.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking, on a 64-bit processor, pointers are 64-bit. So, instead of checking processor features, it maybe possible to use pointers to 'test' it programmatically. It could be as simple as creating a structure with two contiguous pointers and then checking their 'stride'.

Comment: No, won't help with 32 bit code running on 64 bit enabled processor.

Answer (score 0):

C# Code:

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));
if (size == 8)
{
 Text = "64 bit";
}
else if (size == 4)
{
 Text = "32 bit";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can determine the "bitness" by reading

```
/proc/cpuinfo
```

eg.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags
```

if it contains the

```
lm
```

flag it's a x86 64 bit CPU (even if you have 32 bit linux installed)

Not sure if this works for non x86 CPUs as well such as PPC or ARM.