# How can I programmatically determine my processor type?

Tags: c#, java, vbscript, processor

How can I determine programmatically whether my machine is an x86, x64 or an IA64?

Comment: You could open up the computer and look at the CPU.

Are you looking for a code answer?

Comment: perhaps you mean to ask "how can I tell what my machine type is?"

Comment: If you are on Linux try 'uname -m'

Comment: Strange.  The OP didn't mention C#, VBScript, or Java.

Comment: check this SO question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824877/how-can-i-discover-whether-my-cpu-is-32-or-64-bits

Comment: @Sean: He didn't need to. He was (hopefully) saved from a closing.

Comment: This is a programming question:  it should be posted on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows Systems you can get the environment variable PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE.  Here is an MSDN article explaining the values that can be returned.

> ```
> PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
> PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=IA64
> PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
> ```

Comment: Not sure why this got marked down, type into a command line 
echo % PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%

Comment: The MSDN article suggests that this tells you the OS architecture, not the processor type (you can have x86 OS on x86_64 processor).

Answer (score 1):

VBScript, checking the PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE environment variable:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oEnv = oShell.Environment("System")
Select Case LCase(oEnv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"))
  Case "x86"
    ' x86
  Case "amd64"
    ' amd64
  Case "ia64"
    ' ia64
  Case Else
    ' other
End Select
```

VBScript, using WMI:

```
Const PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_X86  = 0
Const PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64 = 6
Const PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_X64  = 9

strComputer = "."

Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
    "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessors = oWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")

For Each oProcessor In colProcessors
  Select Case oProcessor.Architecture
    Case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_X86
      ' x86
    Case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_X64
      ' x64
    Case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64
      ' ia64
    Case Else
      ' other
  End Select
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

  class Class1
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
      RegKey = RegKey.OpenSubKey("HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0");
      Object cpuSpeed = RegKey.GetValue("~MHz");
      Object cpuType  = RegKey.GetValue("VendorIdentifier");
      Console.WriteLine("You have a {0} running at {1} MHz.",cpuType,cpuSpeed);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Instead of getting "VendorIdentifier" you might want to get "ProcessorNameString" which contains the vendors common model name.

Answer (score 0):

cat /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 0):

What's usually more important than the underlying processor is what mode the OS is running in, in ADDITION to the processor that's installed on the host.

Examine the output of "uname -p" (or uname(2))

Intel adopted AMD's extensions for 64-bit instructions so a value of "x86_64" means you're running either an Intel or AMD 64-bit processor, otherwise you're running the regular x86 ISA.

Answer (score -1):

cpu-z is the program you want, it will tell you which processor you have and what extensions it supports

Comment: http://www.cpuid-pro.com/index.php is the page for developers.  This will give loads of detail on CPU, architecture etc if required

Answer (score -1):

In Java you shouldn't need to know. ;)