# How to determine if OS is 32 or 64 bit cross-platform on .NET Standard 1.5?

Tags: c#, operating-system, 32bit-64bit, .net-standard, .net-standard-1.5

I have been looking high and low for a solution to this, but although the question has been asked before the answers no longer apply to .NET Standard 1.5 and its cross-platform way of thinking.  Also, this question is about the *OS Architecture* not the *.NET platform architecture*.

### What I Tried

- [Using C#, how to get whether my machine is 64bit or 32bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031926/using-c-how-to-get-whether-my-machine-is-64bit-or-32bit)
- [How to detect Windows 64-bit platform with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

The best answer, [Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem(v=vs.110).aspx) is an API that is not implemented in .NET Standard 1.5.

The answer

```
/// <summary>Is64s the bit operating system.</summary>
/// <returns></returns>
if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
    // 64Bit
else
    // 32bit
```

is not what I need. Although still possible to do in .NET Standard, it determines the bitness of the .NET platform, not the underlying OS.

Nearly all of the other replies are using `[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]`, which I am almost certain won't work on anything but Windows.

### Question

So, how do I determine the bitness of the underlying OS for all of the [platforms that .NET Standard 1.5 supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) (Linux, iOS, Windows, Android, etc.)?

Comment: so far, almost all implementations i've seen in Mono used the same `IntPtr.Size` trick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell if my application is running as a 32-bit or 64-bit application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266082/how-do-i-tell-if-my-application-is-running-as-a-32-bit-or-64-bit-application)

Comment: @OwenPauling no, it's not. this is specifically about .NET standard which does not offer the kind of functionality every answer in that thread uses

Comment: How about looking at the source for the [Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,1360)?

Comment: @DavidG that code all uses windows specific code

Comment: @TimothyGroote Yes I know, that's why I commented rather than answered. It was just a suggestion for a starting point otherwise the question kinda becomes a library request.

Comment: @TimothyGroote - As I mentioned, IntPtr.Size does not tell the bitness of the underlying OS.

Comment: Please reopen this question. It is not a duplicate of the linked question (this isn't about application bitness at all, it is about the underlying OS).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture`

Comment: you sure? https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.5_ref.md