# java program that determines users CPU size?

Tags: c#, java

Is it possible to create a program in java (Or C#) that can check how big the users CPU power is? If so, what classes/API are available to look up? I can't seem to find anything by googling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically determine my processor type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020581/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-my-processor-type)

Comment: `println("Over 9000");`. What is "how big"?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
System.getenv("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER");
System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
System.getenv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS");
```

<sub>Note: System.getenv returns an OS-dependent mapping and may potentially return null on the keys mentioned above if they are not defined in the current OS.</sub>

You can also consider using the `Runtime` class information:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

If you intend to develop a tool that works like **JConsole**, you should explore the [Java Management](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-use.html) packages. There are a bunch of useful classes there that could suit your requirement.

Comment: This gives a lot of info, but not the speed (maybe for some processors, but not for mine). Are there more?

Comment: @Keppil Try this for a longer list http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/vba/get-environment-variable-values/

Comment: @John: Yeah, wrote a small program to check my computer. Found a few more (PROCESSOR_REVISION, PROCESSOR_LEVEL, PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432), but nothing about speed.

Comment: @Keppil I don't know how to explain this well, but your processor speed is not a constant. I know there is a way to get your clock speed, but it will be different than what is printed on the box.

Answer (score 1):

For c#;

```
var query = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_Processor");
var mc = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

var props = mc.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>()
                .SelectMany(m => m.Properties.Cast<PropertyData>())
                .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);

foreach (var prop in props.Where(kv => kv.Value != null))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.Key, prop.Value);
}
```

It will print something like this

```
AddressWidth = 64
Architecture = 9
Availability = 3
Caption = Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9
CpuStatus = 1
CreationClassName = Win32_Processor
CurrentClockSpeed = 3201
CurrentVoltage = 41
DataWidth = 64
Description = Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9
DeviceID = CPU0
ExtClock = 100
Family = 205
L2CacheSize = 1024
L3CacheSize = 6144
L3CacheSpeed = 0
Level = 6
LoadPercentage = 1
Manufacturer = GenuineIntel
MaxClockSpeed = 3201
Name = Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz
NumberOfCores = 4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors = 4
PowerManagementSupported = False
ProcessorType = 3
Role = CPU
SocketDesignation = CPU 1
SystemCreationClassName = Win32_ComputerSystem
```