# Detect system architecture (x86/x64) while running

Tags: c++, architecture, system, cpu, processor

Is it possible to detect the system/processor architecture while the program *is* running (under windows and under linux) in c++?

Comment: You know that if you compile in x86, it will run in x86 mode on x64 CPUs anyway, right ? Just checking.

Comment: Yes I know. That is what I want to do. But I want to know the architecture.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824877/how-can-i-discover-whether-my-cpu-is-32-or-64-bits

Comment: @Amit: You are right. And this works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, you may use [`__cpuid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). On Linux, you can `open("/proc/cpuinfo")` and look through it.

Here is an example on Windows, based on the example in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page:

```
#include <intrin.h>

bool cpuSupports64()
{
    int CPUInfo[4];
    __cpuid(CPUInfo, 0);
    return (CPUInfo[3] & 0x20000000) || false;
}
```

Comment: /proc/cpuinfo doesn't have any explicit Word size information.

Comment: @Amit: What about `clflush size`?

Comment: @Hosam Aly: Thanks. I didn't know about it. What does 'clflush' stand for btw?

Comment: Can you please give an example on how to do it in windows?

Comment: Oh well. On my 32-bit OS and 32-bit hardware cflush size is still 64!

Comment: @Amit: What's your 32-bit processor type?

Comment: @Hosam: Intel Celeron M 440. Not sure, what you mean my "type".

Comment: @Amit: Hmmm... I'm not sure. Maybe I'm wrong, or maybe your processor supports some form of 64-bit!

Comment: @Levo: I have created an example.

Comment: @Amit: /proc/cpuinfo has a line called "flags :" and if that line has "lm" then the cpu is x64. lm = LongMode

Comment: It doesn't have the 'lm' flag and I knew my processor is 32-bit :)

Answer (score 4):

Under Linux, you can use the `uname` system call.  It fills in this user-allocated struct:

> ```
>   struct utsname {
>            char sysname[];    /* Operating system name (e.g., "Linux") */
>            char nodename[];   /* Name within "some implementation-defined
>                                  network" */
>            char release[];    /* OS release (e.g., "2.6.28") */
>            char version[];    /* OS version */
>            char machine[];    /* Hardware identifier */
>        #ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
>            char domainname[]; /* NIS or YP domain name */
>        #endif
>        };
> ```

The `machine` field will identify the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you intend to do with this information (e.g. select the fastest handcoded assembly code for a specific CPU), under Linux you might want to read /proc/cpuinfo, specifically: the "flags" section, so you can choose between SSE/SSE2 implementation vs. MMX implementation vs. whatever.

Big endian system vs. little endian system is a bit more complicated, refer to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianess

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Processor macros to detect system architecture in c++ code, for example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
#ifdef __x86_64__
    std::cout << "x86" << std::endl;
#endif

#ifdef __arm__
    std::cout << "arm" << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

Here is a reference list of [Pre-defined Compiler Macros](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Architectures/).

**EDIT**:Processor macros is compiler-independant, different compilers have different Processor macros, So it is not possible to detect system architecture this way.

Comment: Also this is while compiling, not while running. So it doesn't answer the question at all