# Determining Windows OS architecture in a non locale-sensitive manner

Tags: c#, windows, architecture, x86-64

I'm looking for a reliable way to determine the Windows OS architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) in a manner that isn't sensitive to Windows version or the system locale/display language. I will be using C# to do this. To clarify, I need the OS architecture, not the processor architecture, and not the application architecture.

I know I can use IntPtr.Size, but this is dependent on the application's target architecture.

I've also tried using System.Management.ManagementClass to get the "OSArchitecture" property from Win32_OperatingSystem. However, the value of this changes depending on the display language. (For example, if I set the display language to Spanish I get "64 bits", when in English it is "64-bit".)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer to [How to detect Windows 64 bit platform with .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Basically, you can do this by first  examining the type of the process and then call the proper method to do the correct check.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is probably what I'll end up going with eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Getting installed Windows Architecture:

```
    string getOSArchitecture()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)))
            return "64-bit";
        return "32-bit";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On .NET 4.0 or higher there is a [System.Environment.Is64bitOperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64Bitoperatingsystem.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has the same question, this seems to do the trick as well. I'm not certain how robust it is:

```
public bool Is64Bit() {
    return (System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)") != null);
}
```