# how to get Operating System Details in C# code

Tags: c#, wmi

i need to get OsArchitecture means Bits of O/s , i used Win32_OperatingSystem but its "OsArchitecture "is not work for all type Operating System

```
ManagementObjectSearcher objOSDetails = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
           ManagementObjectCollection osDetailsCollection = objOSDetails.Get();
 foreach( ManagementObject mo in osDetailsCollection )
  {
    String  _operatingSysBits = mo["OSArchitecture"].ToString();

  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect Windows 64 bit platform with .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [IntPtr.Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.size.aspx). It will be 4 on a 32-bit platform, and 8 on a 64-bit platform (unless your process is running in 32bit mode).

Comment: It'll still be 4 on a 64-bit platform running a .NET app compiled for 32-bit.

Comment: Not if running as a 32 bit process on Windows 64.

Comment: what is IntPtr.Size  and where to get it.

Comment: @Shantanu Edited answer with link, and clarification for running in 32bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

for .NET 4.0 there is Environment.is64BitOperatingSystem

or

```
    ManagementObject Mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'");
    object o = Mo["Architecture"];
    UInt16 sp = (UInt16)(o);

    if (sp == 0)
    {
        //86
    } else if (sp == 9)
    {
        //64
    }

    Mo.Dispose();
```