# C# How do you get the operating system architecture (x86 or x64)?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-2.0, x86, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect Windows 64 bit platform with .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

How can I retrieve the operating system architecture (x86 or x64) with .NET 2.0?

I have not found any good method to get the OS architecture on Google. What I found was how to tell whether the process is 32-bit or 64-bit.

If there isn't anyway to find out in .NET 2.0 please tell me. :)

Comment: Duplicate of [How to detect Windows 64 bit platform with .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Comment: use this: "Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not the accepted answer in the duplicate question, but this is how I'd do it:

Use `GetEnvironmentVariable` to look for the PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 variable. If it doesn't exist, you must be running 32bit:

```
bool is64bit = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"));
```

Comment: This seems dramatically simpler than the accepted answer in the dup.

Comment: Apparently this is set for WOW64 processes (i.e. 32-bit code running on 64-bit OS).  Seems like a kind of flaky thing to check.  What's to stop me from setting that environment variable, just for kicks, or just because I like giving your code a hard time?

Comment: @asveikau - Nothing at all. It's a simpler piece of code, but like you said, not 100% reliable.