# determine if the os is 32 bit or 64 bit in c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect Windows 64 bit platform with .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Hi all, I am currently developing an application in c# and would like to know if it is possible using code to determine if the OS the computer is running is 32bit or 64 bit. The program I am writing is compiled as 32 bit but need to know if it is running on 64 bit or not.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [How to detect Windows 64 bit platform with .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Comment: None of the answers in the linked thread will work when the code lives in a DLL compiled with AnyCPU as the platform target.  Not a problem here though, good to know you're running x86.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Why would the detection fail in the case you describe? I can't see a reason why this should be the case for the accepted answer.