# How I can know programmatically what platform the code is running under?

Tags: c#, .net

How i can know from the code if i run under x86 OS or under x64 OS .

Thanks for help.

Comment: The correct answer depends a great deal on *why* you need to know.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I need from application to run 3rd party applications and I need to know what to run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following `Environment` properties:

```
System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem

System.Environment.Is64BitProcess
```

**Update**

For platforms previous to .Net 4.0, the following can be used to implement the above functionality:

[How to detect Windows 64-bit platform with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net/336729#336729)

Comment: Please note that this is for .NET 4.0 or greater.

Comment: I know you corrected your misspelling but its nice to know I'm not the only one who goes dyslexic when trying to spell environment. :)

Comment: @ChaosPandion I am dyslexic. Your username is particularly hard to spell. The word 'chaos' is almost capable of sending my brain into recursive meltdown. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
bool is64bit = IntPtr.Size == 8;
```

Comment: This doesn't tell you the platform - you can still be on a 64bit OS, but running under Wow64.

Comment: @Reed - Indeed, but I don't believe they care what the platform is. OP, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Reed - His question is how to determine if the application is running on a 64-bit operating system or 32-bit operating system ( x86 ).  The problem with your suggestion is that boolean would return true if the application was built as a x86 application specifically.

Comment: @Ramhound - Are you sure about that? Unfortunately, I can't test this right now but I was under the impression that even x86 emulation using 8-byte pointers.

Comment: I have tested this and @Ramhound is correct. If you build with x86, pointers are 4 bytes wide on an x64 OS.