# C#: How to tell architecture of machine

Tags: c#, architecture, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect Windows 64 bit platform with .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

At a low level, how can I tell if a particular machine is 64-bit or 32-bit?  I have a Firebird d/b that appears to be sensitive to the 64-bit architecture, and I want to verify that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like the [`Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx) property is exactly what you need.

Comment: Touché, +1. Didn't know that existed.

Comment: @Brad: Probably because this is new in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell if you are running under a 64 bit OS with the `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` property. If you have a 64bit machine but with a 32 bit OS installed then everything will be running as 32 bit.