# Framework or Framework 64?

Tags: asp.net, .net, 32bit-64bit

Is there a way I can tell what framework I've been using as I need to access machine.config?

Framework or Framework 64 under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\ directory both have the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at this article: If you are using .NET 4, it has two properties in the Environment class, Is64BitOperatingSystem and Is64BitProcess. give them a try.

and have a look on this article, it's really useful: 
[How to detect programmatically whether you are running on 64-bit Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/01/364563.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

From within the code? In C# 4.0 `Environment.Is64BitProcess`, in < 4.0 `IntPtr.Size`. And read [How to detect Windows 64-bit platform with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Comment: Be careful of capital letters! It is specifically Environment.Is64BitProcess