# 32 bit or 64 bit using c#

Tags: c#, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect Windows 64 bit platform with .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

I would like to read keys of the `Uninstall` subkey of Windows registry.

So in order to do that, I need to check the bit edition of OS, is the following code sufficient or not?

```
        public enum OSEdition
        {
            Bit32,
            Bit64
        };

        public static OSEdition GetOSEdition
        {
            get
            {
                if (System.IntPtr.Size == 8)
                {
                    return OSEdition.Bit64;
                }
                else
                {
                    return OSEdition.Bit32;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well there's [`Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx)... why not use that?

Comment: @Jeff: It requires .NET 4 - when targetting e.g. XP and Vista, too, and the software is published via download you usually want to use a framework version that is likely to be already installed.

Comment: @Thief: Of course but nothing was specified here so I will always assume current version unless mentioned otherwise.