# Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable to check os version 32bit/64bit

Tags: c#, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect Windows 64 bit platform with .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Project : C# .5

Description: The code checks whether the underlying machine is 64 bit or 32 bit OS.
Return Value: The code always return a `null` value. **WHY ?**

```
  if (8 == IntPtr.Size || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"))))
            {
                return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SysWOW64");
            }
            return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("system32");
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` or `Environment.Is64BitProcess`?

Answer (score 2):

The code returns null because the variable that it is returning isn't set. Better way to check if you're on a 64 bit environment is to call Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem and Environment.Is64BitProcess

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem) 
{
    return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SysWOW64"); 
}
else
{
    return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("system32");       
}
```