# 32 or 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect Windows 64 bit platform with .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

I'm using this code ti check if the machine is 64 or 32 bit:

```
    public static string GetOSBit()
    {
        bool is64bit = Is64Bit();
        if (is64bit)
            return "64 bit";
        else
            return "32 bit";
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool IsWow64Process([In] IntPtr hProcess, [Out] out bool lpSystemInfo);

    public static bool Is64Bit()
    {
        bool retVal;
        IsWow64Process(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out retVal);
        return retVal;
    }
```

I have a 32 bit machine and it works ok for me. It returns "32 bit". My friend however also has a 32 bit machine, but has installed virtual machine which is 64 bit. The code above returns "32 bit" for her virtual machine, although it's 64 bit.
I work in C#, .Net 2.0.

Comment: As the API suggests, this describes a process, not the machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `IsWow64Process` determines whether the specified process is running under WOW64. So basically it returns `true` when called for the 32-bit process running under 64-bit OS.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem%28VS.100%29.aspx).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net) for more answers and discussion.

---

Edit: Oh, didn't see the question is about .net 2.0. (Keeping the answer for reference.)