# How to change variable value depending on architecture

Tags: c#, compilation

Title is clear: how can I change a value in C# depending on destination architecture? In particular, I want to change a string depending on x86 or x64.
Many Thanks!

Edit: I need to check if an x64 Office version is installed if my application is x64 too.

Comment: No, question and title are not clear. Change a string from what to what?

Comment: No such a Question, What do you mean?

Comment: `Environment.Is64BitProcess` might be useful.

Comment: What do you want to do if you're running on a 32-bit CLR but on an x64 processor?

Comment: Ok, Thanks! `Environment.Is64BitProcess` works. I didn't know there were such a simple possibility to "read" that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Environment.Is64BitProcess` should do the trick

Comment: The simplest way. I'm a newbie, APIs are still not well known to me.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you what you're looking for:

```
 string platform = IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "x86" : "x64";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IntPtr.Size

```
string foobar = String.Empty;

if (IntPtr.Size == 4) //32-bit
    foobar = "foo";
else if (IntPtr.Size == 8) //64-bit
    foobar = "bar";
```

see also:

[How to detect Windows 64-bit platform with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

The answer chosen is pretty darn good.