# Detecting whether a C++ app is running on 32 or 64-bit Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, 64-bit

This is a reasonably popular question, but all the answers pretty much say: "Use IsWow64Process function". The problem with that is it returns FALSE if the application is 64-bit. I want a solution that works regardless of my app's bitness.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect Windows 64-bit platform with .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Comment: @AhmedMasud: do you know the difference between .NET and C++ / WinAPI?

Comment: This does fall in the category of "how can you not know".  You make a very specific configuration change in your project to target x64.  Making another one to define a macro is not any different and is eminently portable.  Using something like sizeof(void*) in your code is not exactly a hack either, the compiler sorts this out at compile time so can optimize away chunks of code.  Or use a predefined compiler macro, like _WIN64.

Comment: did you go read all the answers there?? there is a NON .NET C++/WinAPI answer listed in the replies to that question :P

Comment: @AhmedMasud: I don't like the answer relying on environmental variables either, they might be deleted.

Comment: Okay then I have another reference for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/01/364563.aspx and I am retracting the close vote  the issues are nicely discussed there.

Comment: @AhmedMasud: Yep, thanks, figured it out already. Funny how I didn't realize it immediately :)

Comment: Add your answer below I'll vote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a function to call the Win32 API function `IsWow64Process()` for 32bit process and return `true` for 64bit process.

```
bool is_64bit(void)
{
#if defined(_WIN64)
    return true;  // 64-bit programs run only on Win64
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    BOOL f64 = FALSE;
    return IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &f64) && f64;
#endif
}
```

Comment: Your `#if` ... `#elif` ... `#endif` does not contain an `#else` clause. Is this intentional? In this particular case the compiler will issue an error if none of the preprocessor symbols are defined. In general I prefer to be explicit and use an `#error` preprocessor directive in cases like this.