# GetVersionEx() is deprecated: should I use Environment.OSVersion?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I am intending to write code to determine if the OS is Windows XP, so I can set the LOCALAPPDATA environment variable to work-around a whole load of code which uses ExpandEnvironmentVariables() heavily.

To make it even more fun, some code is written in VB6, and some code is written in C# 4.0 . Looking at the documentation for GetVersionEx(), there are strong suggestions that this API call will be deprecated from Windows 8.1 onwards. But no problem, there is a different set of API calls (VerifyVersionInfo / VerSetConditionMask) I can use. With VB6, there is no choice - I have to use the API call.

However, with my C# code, there appears to be no obvious equivalent. There is Environment.OSVersion, but this seems to be a hacked together set of data from disparate sources, and there isn't anything with the subtlety of the VerifyVersionInfo() API.

Is there a wrapper for this API call. If not, should I bother implementating it myself?

[Added]
Or otherwise, maybe someone might have some internal information about *how* the Environment.OSVersion is implemented?

Comment: You're concerned about using a function that may shortly be deprecated, to determine an operating system that will shortly not be supported anyway?

Comment: When people pay you lots of money for code to run on an obsolete OS, it is worth it. On the other hand, we don't want to write code which is obviously immediately obsolete on later OSs. "VerifyVersionInfo" is probably going to last longer than "GetVersionEx"!

Comment: In the C# code, could you use P/Invoke to call the same API's which the VB6 code is  calling, if that is what you're looking for?

Comment: @JasonEvans - Yes, I could do, and I may well do so. However, I prefer to do things via the framework wherever possible.

Comment: [How the Environment.OSVersion is implemented](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Environment@cs/1305376/Environment@cs)

Comment: Thanks, but I just found it out in probably the same way the author of that document did it!

Comment: By downloading the [.NET Framework source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx)?

Comment: @JimMischel Um. No. But I have to admit that I didn't know MS was officially releasing it. :-) Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

First of all it is important to understand what `Deprecated` means. It means that the function either is critically broken (such as some early threading), or that it's been superseded (replaced) with new functionality. In this case it is the latter.

From the documentation on [GetVersionEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there is a link suggesting to use [Version Helper APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

One part of this page is specifically important:

> Note  These APIs are defined by versionhelper.h, which is included in
>   the Windows 8.1 Preview software development kit (SDK). This file can
>   be used with other Microsoft Visual Studio releases to implement the
>   same functionality for Windows versions prior to Windows 8.1 Preview.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly fine to use GetVersionEx. It won't be removed from Windows for a very long time, if ever. Microsoft has a long track record of maintaining compatibility with old programs. For example, you can still call the Win16 APIs that were deprecated 20 years ago.

Comment: Api will not be removed, but it could just don't give the expected result. version in 8.1 seems to decide to lie to us. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @ColdCat It gives the result desired by the asker of this question. Am I on XP or not? Nuances with 8.1 are not the issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - True it seems that it will only lie for later versions, but I am worried by the text says it may be "unavailable" after Win 8.1. Up to now, I would agree with you that MS has been very good about backwards compatibility (with the exception of VB). But this is a warning I am taking seriously.

Comment: When they take it out, 95% programs will not start. That will never happen.

Comment: Microsoft does not always maintain "compatibility with old programs". Windows Help files were supported in 32-bit versions of Windows but not in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I added an additional part to my original question about whether anybody knew about the internals of the Environment.OSVersion object. After searching around this site for a few minutes, I found this question:

[How to detect Windows 64-bit platform with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Now, the "official" answer itself wasn't very interesting to me, but the second answer from Phil Devaney mentioned an application called "Reflector" that appeared to do some sort of magic. So I downloaded it, and blow me down, I was able to decompile the P-Code for the Environment.OSVersion object's constructor:

```
Win32Native.OSVERSIONINFO osVer = new Win32Native.OSVERSIONINFO();
            if (!GetVersion(osVer))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(GetResourceString("InvalidOperation_GetVersion"));
            }
```

So that's it: Environment.OSVersion internally uses GetVersion, a function which might not behave itself in future days. Looks as if VerifyVersionInfo and P/Invoke is the way to go on this one.

I will now have to download .NET 4.5 on a different machine and see if that implementation is any different.

Comment: If you want to detect XP, GetVersion and GetVersionEx are fine.

Comment: Well, I would *hope so*. But I don't like Microsoft's rather ambiguous comments re. the actual functions themselves for Win 8.1+.

Comment: MSDN is full of nonsense boilerplate like that. Clearly they cannot take those functions away. Break every single .net app? Not going to happen.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - After the VB6 debacle, can you be sure? :-)  Well, I think the answer here is not to sweat this particular issue *too* much. But going forwards, I won't be using these APIs.

Comment: VB6 still works. VB6 apps still run on Windows 8.1. I do wonder how IsWindows8Point1OrGreater is implemented on Win 2k. I bet there's a call to GetVersionEx in there!! Note that all these recent APIs have min supported version on Win2k. But many other APIs are listed as having min level XP when in fact they exist on NT4. MS is desperate for you not to call GetVersionEx directly.so it's trying to scare you. But from C# you cannot include the version helper header.

Comment: @DavidHefferman You obviously were not a VB6 programmer back in the early 2000s. Despite all the good intentions by MS, they really messed up backwards compatibility between VB6 and VB.NET. Suddenly, definitions of types changed, and a lot of code that worked before, didn't work. None of the VB6 programmers I know went onto VB.NET. Basically, a massive loss of trust between MS and its programmers happened. Once you've invested time and energy in a platform going nowhere, it does colour your reactions.

Comment: That's not at all what I said. VB6 still works and VB6 programs still run. That's what I said. VB.net was never intended to be backwards compatible with VB6. FWIW, where did the VB6 programmers go? Anyone that I knew who programmed in VB6 hated it and only stayed with it through inertia.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think you should let the killing of development of VB6 influence backwards compatibility of the OS. MS track record there is superb. Compare life as a Mac OS programmer.

Comment: Actually, thinking more, I bet that `IsWindows8Point1OrGreater` is implemented with `VerifyVersionInfo`. I think p/invoking that is a reasonable approach. I still think that `GetVersion` is a perfectly trustworthy way to determine XP or not, but I would also say that `VerifyVersionInfo` is also a fine way to do so.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think that IsWindows8Point1OrGreater is simply a macro.

Comment: I know. I originally thought it would be implemented on top of `GetVersion` because older platforms do not have `VerifyVersionInfo`. But it seems that `VerifyVersionInfo` has been around for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Mark)
Maybe it will interesting for you [GetVersionExEx](https://bitbucket.org/AnyCPU/findversion)
But please note that VerifyVersionInfo may also be deprecated in later releases of Windows OS (as stated by ms tech guy in msdn social forum).

This code depends on VerifyVersionInfo and provides same usage experience. Also bisection algo was used in code.

Version Helper API for requests to API, this code for exact values.

Thanks)

Comment: Note that ``VersionHelpers.h`` just uses ``VeriyVersionInfo``.