# how to spoof MAC address via code

Tags: c#, mac-address

I'm trying to spoof the MAC address of the computer that executes my program. Right now I'm getting the current MAC address of the machine using the 'getmac' command via cmd, then I want to change it via the 'RegistryKey' class(windows.system32).

The issue is that I don't know the string to pass to the `OpenSubKey` method.

For example this is the method to read the current MAC with registry key reading:

```
 private string readMAC()
    {
        RegistryKey rkey;
        string MAC;
        rkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class\\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\\0012", true); //--->this is the string to change 
        MAC = (string)rkey.GetValue("NetworkAddress");
        rkey.Close();
        return MAC;
    }
```

Comment: Can you change the MAC address?  I thought that was determined by the hardware you're running on.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Most drivers allow the MAC address to be changed. Among other reasons because they are not guaranteed unique - I repeatedly got bches with multipe NIC's with the same address (as technically it only must be unique within one broadcast domain).

Comment: Actually ALL Drivers these days MUST allow it. How you think a Hyper-V network can otherwise attach more than one MAC address ;) Modern higher end chipsets must be VERY flexible in this area.

Comment: What's wrong with the key you're passing to `OpenSubKey` in your example code?

Comment: there's nothing wrong but i've to change it if the code is running on a different computer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction, but you're going to have to figure out the code:

1. look in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\` and you'll see a few sub keys corresponding to the interfaces in the "network connections" control panel.  Probably only one will have a valid IP, and the others will have 0.0.0.0  You'll need to do some pattern matching to figure out which one is the right one.
2. get the key name for the interface (it's a GUID, or at least looks like one), and go back to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}` and check each one's `NetCfgInstanceId` value (or search) for the GUID of the interface.

Comment: thank you so much for the tip, probably is the best way, i'll follow it.

Comment: Sure, good luck.  BTW, if you like this answer, don't forget to accept it (click the check-mark).

Answer (score 6):

I got curious so I pulled the source for [MadMACs](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/madmacs-mac-spoofer). Turned out to be pretty straightforward to port the core logic to C#, so here it is if anyone is interested.

```
private const string baseReg =
    @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\";

public static bool SetMAC(string nicid, string newmac)
{
    bool ret = false;
    using (RegistryKey bkey = GetBaseKey())
    using (RegistryKey key = bkey.OpenSubKey(baseReg + nicid))
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            key.SetValue("NetworkAddress", newmac, RegistryValueKind.String);

            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE Index = " + nicid));

            foreach (ManagementObject o in mos.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>())
            {
                o.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
                o.InvokeMethod("Enable", null);
                ret = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetNicIds()
{
    using (RegistryKey bkey = GetBaseKey())
    using (RegistryKey key = bkey.OpenSubKey(baseReg))
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            foreach (string name in key.GetSubKeyNames().Where(n => n != "Properties"))
            {
                using (RegistryKey sub = key.OpenSubKey(name))
                {
                    if (sub != null)
                    {
                        object busType = sub.GetValue("BusType");
                        string busStr = busType != null ? busType.ToString() : string.Empty;
                        if (busStr != string.Empty)
                        {
                            yield return name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static RegistryKey GetBaseKey()
{
    return RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
        RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
        InternalCheckIsWow64() ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32);
}
```

For brevity's sake, I've left out the implementation of `InternalCheckIsWow64()`, but that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336729/866618). Without this, I was running into issues with not finding the registry I wanted due to structural differences between 32- and 64-bit OSes.

Obligatory disclaimer -- play with the registry at your own peril.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0004\NetworkAddress