# How to change MAC-address without 02 0A 06 0E limitation

Tags: c#, mac-address

I have a problem
I have written a program with c# that it should change MAC-address but windows says I can set MAC-addresses that start with 02 or 06 or 0A or 0E
What should I do?
Can I disable that permission?

Comment: MAC address is preserved in registry, you can set what you want. All necessary already is on SO here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310464/how-to-spoof-mac-address-via-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is  that you can't because certain values are reserved, in much the same way as certain IP addresses have reserved meanings.

The problem you are encountering is that there is a difference between local and universal MAC addresses.

The format of MAC addresses is defined by the the IEE 802 Standard. Windows, or C# are almost certainly enforcing the standard, although you don't say what method you are using to attempt the change.

For a diagram of MAC address layout, please see:
[IEEE 802 layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MAC-48_Address.svg)

Comment: I change local MAC address. computers aren't in any networks

Comment: The device does not need to be connected to a network for the rules to apply. Most libraries will only allow you to make valid local address changes.
Because of this, you will need to have the lowest bit of the first octet set to 0 (indicating it is unique), and the second lowest bit in the first octet set to 1 (meaning locally administered).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible just as others MAC ids in Linux

It's not possible in windows

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 Enterprise and Professional using Hyper-V creating a virtual network are possible to use any MAC address without the 2,6,A,E limitations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/connect-to-network

The trick are the original wifi adapter program are communicate through the internal adapter program what created the Hyper-V program and the user can change the MAC address without limitation using a MAC spoofing software like TMAC Technicum MAC address changer. I tested with Wireless Network Watcher program and all spoofed MAC addresses working without limitations this way.

The communication goes this way with the setup 1.The wifi adapter ->2. Original wifi network adapter program with the 2, 6, A, E, X2-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX limitations  -> 3. Hyper-V  adapter program without MAC limitations (you must change the MAC address here) -> 4. The wifi network what see the Hyper-V spoofed MAC address.