# Spoofing MAC ID programmatically

Tags: c#, mac-address

I am trying to change System MAC ID programatically and am using the following code but it does not work as `RegistryKey key = bkey.OpenSubKey(Constants.baseReg + nicid)` is null.
how can i fix this issue. I am running Win7 64 bit OS if that matters.

also `public const string baseReg = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\";`
and nicid = the current mac ID of the first network adapter

```
public static bool SetMAC(string nicid, string newmac)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        using (RegistryKey bkey = GetBaseKey())
        using (RegistryKey key = bkey.OpenSubKey(Constants.baseReg + nicid))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                key.SetValue("NetworkAddress", newmac, RegistryValueKind.String);

                ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                    new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE Index = " + nicid));

                foreach (ManagementObject o in mos.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>())
                {
                    o.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
                    o.InvokeMethod("Enable", null);
                    ret = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310464/how-to-spoof-mac-address-via-code

Comment: I already checked that and the Mentioned solution {with code}  does not work.

Comment: Well, you are using the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26576104/2265446) but you are missing in your question the `GetBaseKey()` function. Have you `regedit` and checked if the registry key does exists and the user executing the code has permission?

Comment: I have all the functions from that code and little extra to fetch the MAC ID of the first adapter. 
yes i manually checked and the key Exist and i tried running in Administrator mode as well. 

I am now trying out this answer => https://stackoverflow.com/a/22311067/10280431
but stuck after the 2nd step as i dont understand were or how the new MAC value is assigned and the Person who Responded with that answer doesn't explain either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i Solved this Issue after hours of digging and browsing.
on the side note, there is a problem with this one, it only uses the first adapter from the ActiveAdapterMAC list.

PSS - This Code isn't the best one and i have few fixes to do. but i am sure this can get you to the right direction.
here is the Code to get the current active network adapter NICID then use that to set the MAC ID

```
public static void GetAllNetworkAdapters()
    {           
        NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters.Where(a => a.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up))
        {                
            ActiveAdapters.Add(adapter.Id);
            string MAC = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
            ActiveAdapterMAC.Add(MAC);
            Logger.LogGenericText($"Adapter Properties => {adapter.Id} / {MAC}");
        }
    }

public static string GetSubKeyValue()
    {
        RegistryKey Base = GetBaseKey();
        RegistryKey Key = Base.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}", true);
        string SelectedKey = null;
        string[] Values = Key.GetSubKeyNames();
        try
        {
            foreach (var key in Values)
            {
                RegistryKey ValueChecker = Base.OpenSubKey(Constants.baseReg + key, true);
                string NetCFID = ValueChecker.GetValue("NetCfgInstanceId").ToString();
                if (NetCFID == ActiveAdapters[0])
                {
                    SelectedKey = key;
                }
                ValueChecker.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if(ex is SecurityException)
            {
                Key.Close();
                return SelectedKey;
            }
        }

        Key.Close();
        return SelectedKey;
    }

public static void ConfigMAC(bool Reset = false, bool RegisterDefault = false)
    {
        RegistryKey Base = GetBaseKey();
        string NICID = GetSubKeyValue();
        string NewMAC = GenerateMACAddress();
        CachedNICID = NICID;

        if (Config.WifiConnection)
        {
            NewMAC = GetRandomWifiMacAddress();
        }

        if (RegisterDefault)
        {               
            string CurrentMAC = GetMacIDWithCache();
            Constants.CurrentMACID = CurrentMAC;
            try
            {
                RegistryKey RegisterKey = Base.OpenSubKey(Constants.baseReg + NICID, true);
                if (RegisterKey.GetValue(Constants.DefaultMAC) != null)
                {
                    RegisterKey.Close();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    RegisterKey.SetValue(Constants.DefaultMAC, CurrentMAC);
                    RegisterKey.Close();
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogGenericText(ex.ToString());
                return;
            }                      
        }

        if (Reset)
        {
            DeleteKey(NICID, true);
            return;
        }

        Logger.LogGenericText("Opening Sub Key => " + Constants.baseReg + NICID);
        RegistryKey Key = Base.OpenSubKey(Constants.baseReg + NICID, true);

        string[] KeyValues = Key.GetValueNames();

        if (!KeyValues.Contains(Constants.MacValue))
        {
            Key.SetValue(Constants.MacValue, NewMAC);
            Logger.LogGenericText("Value Set for " + Constants.MacValue + " as " + NewMAC);                
            Constants.CurrentMACID = NewMAC;
            Task.Run(() => ResetAdapter(NICID));
        }
        else
        {
            DeleteKey(NICID, false);
            Key.SetValue(Constants.MacValue, NewMAC);
            Logger.LogGenericText("Value Set for " + Constants.MacValue + " as " + NewMAC);
            Constants.CurrentMACID = NewMAC;
            Task.Run(() => ResetAdapter(NICID));
        }
        Key.Close();
    }    

    public static void DeleteKey(string Nicid, bool Restart)
    {
        Logger.LogGenericText("Deleting Previous Changed MAC...");
        RegistryKey Base = GetBaseKey();
        RegistryKey ResetKey = Base.OpenSubKey(Constants.baseReg + Nicid, true);
        ResetKey.DeleteValue(Constants.MacValue);
        ResetKey.Close();

        if (Restart)
        {
            Task.Run(() => ResetAdapter(Nicid));
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }            
    }

    public static void ResetAdapter(string Nicid)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher
                            (new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE Index = " + Nicid));

        foreach (ManagementObject o in mos.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>())
        {
            Logger.LogGenericText("Disabling Adapter and Waiting for 6 Seconds.");
            o.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
            Task.Delay(6000).Wait();
            o.InvokeMethod("Enable", null);
            Logger.LogGenericText("New MAC ID Set Sucessfully!");
        }
    }
```

How does it work?
I used this logic

> This software just writes a value into the windows registry. When the Network Adapter Device is enabled, windows searches for the registry value 'NetworkAddress' in the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1- 08002bE10318}[ID of NIC e.g. 0001]. If a value is present, windows will use it as MAC address, if not, windows will use the hard coded manufacturer provided MAC address. Some Network Adapter drivers have this facility built-in. It can be found in the Advance settings tab in the Network Adapter's Device properties in Windows Device Manager.

From => [TMAC](https://technitium.com/tmac/) website.

Comment: I am facing the same problem too. Can you help me the full working code to change mac in C#?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Most of the logic and the functions for it are already in this answer.