# Read large CSV in PowerShell parse multiple columns for unique values save results based on oldest value in column

Tags: powershell, csv, unique, large-data

I have a large 10 million row file (currently CSV). I need to read through the file, and remove duplicate items based on multiple columns.

Example line of data would look something like:

ComputerName, IPAddress, MacAddress, CurrentDate, FirstSeenDate

I would want to check MacAddress and ComputerName for duplicates and if a duplicate is discovered keep the unique entry with the oldest FirstSeenDate.

I have read a CSV into a variable using import-csv and then processed the variable using sort-object...etc but it's horribly slow.

```bsh
$data | Group-Object -Property ComputerName,MaAddress | ForEach-Object{$_.Group | Sort-Object -Property FirstSeenDate | Select-Object -First 1}
```

I am thinking I could use stream.reader and read the CSV line by line building a unique array based on array contains logic.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use Python if performance were a major concern. Or LogParser.

However, if I had to use PowerShell, I would probably try something like this:

```
$CultureInfo = [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$DateFormat = 'M/d/yyyy' # Use whatever date format is appropriate

# We need to convert the strings that represent dates. You can skip the ParseExact() calls if the dates are already in a string sortable format (e.g., yyyy-MM-dd).
$Data = Import-Csv $InputFile | Select-Object -Property ComputerName, IPAddress, MacAddress, @{n = 'CurrentDate'; e = {[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.CurrentDate, $DateFormat, $CultureInfo)}}, @{n = 'FirstSeenDate'; e = {[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.FirstSeenDate, $DateFormat, $CultureInfo)}}

$Results = @{}
foreach ($Record in $Data) {
    $Key = $Record.ComputerName + ';' + $Record.MacAddress
    if (!$Results.ContainsKey($Key)) {
        $Results[$Key] = $Record
    }
    elseif ($Record.FirstSeenDate -lt $Results[$Key].FirstSeenDate) {
        $Results[$Key] = $Record
    }
}

$Results.Values | Sort-Object -Property ComputerName, MacAddress | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

That may very well be faster because `Group-Object` is often a bottleneck even though it is quite powerful.

If you really want to try using a stream reader, try using the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.0), which is a part of the .Net framework in spite of it's slightly misleading name. You can access it by running `Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic`.

Answer (score -1):

You could do an import in a database (i.e. SQLite [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947916/import-csv-to-sqlite) )
and then query:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(FirstSeenDate) AS FirstSeenDate, 
  ComputerName, 
  IPAddress, 
  MacAddress
FROM importedData
GROUP BY ComputerName, IPAddress, MacAddress
```

Comment: This won't be what OP is asking for if the computer's IP address has changed. You'll have to use a window function like ROW_NUMBER() or RANK(), a correlated subquery, or a self-join to get what he's looking for.

Comment: Not only the IP address can change, ComputerName and [Macaddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310464/how-to-spoof-mac-address-via-code) can also change

Comment: They're not concerned about that. That's why they said "I would want to check MacAddress and ComputerName for duplicates". They want to know the first instance that a computer name is seen with a given MAC address, so the key fields are the host name and the MAC. The IP address might change, but it's not what they're looking for.