# How do I change properties on control panel with visual studio

Tags: c#, button, properties, visual-studio-2019, controlpanel

hello here is my question: I recently figured how to change my mac address through control panel but I want to make it into a button on visual studio. I have no idea how to change things on OTHER apps with visual studio. My only experience is ProcessStartinfo which only opens the app and doesn't do anything else. so i'm wondering if theres a way to code something into a button where when you press it, it goes to this specific part in control panel and changes a property. for example: when I click this button on my form, it goes to the control panel then network and sharing center and then goes to my internet connection into properties then changes my network address (mac address). because i don't want to manually do it everytime, I have an idea on how to do it but when i searched it up it was just all tools to open specific parts in control panel and no info i needed which is actually CHANGING the properties in control panel. ok this might not be understandable but I hope you know what i'm saying. this is what i have right now

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
            ps.FileName = "Control Panel.lnk";
           
            Process.Start(ps);
        }
```

I hope someone can help me with this

Comment: Unfortunately unless you have the source code for the other app or the other app offers a way to integrate with it (in which case you'll need to consult the documentation). However, in this case it looks like what you're doing is writing your own app with a button that will change the MAC address, so what you're seeking is an API or other interface to make that change to the system. Check out the options presented [in how to spoof MAC address via code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310464/how-to-spoof-mac-address-via-code).

Comment: thanks i will try it out!

Comment: i figured it out thanks for showing me that post!!! sorry how do i close this question or make it answered i'm new around here? nvm

Comment: If you see a **delete** link at the bottom of your post you can opt to use that but otherwise it should get marked as a duplicate and closed by the community as more users vote on it. I think that occurs at reputation 15? https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges